# Remove an element at a specific position from every sublist

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list such as:

```
a = [[1,'b',2],[3,':',4],[5,':',6]]
```

I want to remove the 'b' and ':' characters so that I end up with:

```
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

(Note that the fact that these characters are in the second position of each sublist is just an accident of my choice of example - the real data set I am working on has the same characters in random positions).

I have chosen to use a list comprehension to do this.  Here is an example of the code to iterate over each item of the sublists:

```
for list in a:
    for number in list:
        print number
```

But when I implement my list comprehension instead of the print statement like this:

```
b = []

for list in a:
    for number in list:
        b = [number for number in list if number != 'b' and number != ':']
        print b
```

I get the following output:

```
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[3, 4]
[3, 4]
[5, 6]
[5, 6]
[5, 6]
```

My question is, why are there three copies of each sublist? I was expecting

```
[1,2]
[3,4]
[5,6]
```

Any help and/or guidance would be much appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Are you really trying to remove non-numeric elements? Or are there other elements such as 'a', 'xyz' that you intend to keep?

Comment: because you are looping twice; once over the initial list and once over each sublist.

Comment: You just print in the wrong place. Try "de-indent" it into the main loop

Comment: Aside from actual problem, you should not use `list` as variabale as it is `keyword` in python.

Comment: You have 3*3 elements, you are printing from 2nd depth of the for loop
so it will print 3*3 i.e 9 elements

Comment: @has `list()` is a builtin, not a keyword, assigning to a keyword raises an error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you're trying to remove is `b` and `:`, you can use a nested list comprehension with a set membership test:

```
a_new = [[y for y in x if y not in {'b', ':'}] for x in a]
```

Although, if you'd like to generalise this to remove any non-numeric element, filter with an `isinstance` check:

```
import numbers
a_new = [[y for y in x if isinstance(y, numbers.Number)] for x in a]
```

Note that this is the same as:

```
a_new = []
for i in a:
    a_new.append([])
    for j in i:
        if isinstance(j, numbers.Number):
            a_new[-1].append(j)
```

Note that you only need 2 loops here (your code has 3 which is why everything is replicated 3 times - the number of items in each inner list!).

```
print(a_new)
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Another note here, `numbers.Number` is an injected superclass of *any* numeric value (including irrational values). If your use case does not include complex numbers, you may instead want to use `numbers.Rational` or `numbers.Real`.

Final note, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49128622/removing-elements-inside-lists-of-lists-in-python-2-7/49128699?noredirect=1#comment85261969_49128622), please don't use `list`/`dict` other such names as variables, they end up shadowing the actual builtins.

Comment: why not simply `y.isdigit()`?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis The assumption here is that there are mixed strings and numbers. `y.isdigit()` would work if everything was a string.

Comment: @Chris_Rands I somehow thought the sublists were like `['1', 'b', ...]`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
d=[[number2 for number2 in number if number2 != 'b' and number2 != ':'] for number in a ]
```

output:

> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

Comment: Hmm, OP mentioned that it was only a coincidence that those values lie in i[1]. This won't be the case in general.

Comment: OP said that the characters will not always be in position with index 1

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an [XY problem](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi5lPXjwdfZAhXGIMAKHS5CCmAQFjAAegQIABAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F66377%2Fwhat-is-the-xy-problem&usg=AOvVaw1RW8UpIl7QYxoW-PU7zAk9). Below are some options, depending on what you are *really* looking to do.

**Only include numeric types and return list**

```
arr = [[1,'b',2], [3,':',4], [5,':',6]]

def is_num(x):
    return isinstance(x, (int, float))

arr = [[i for i in k if is_num(i)] for k in arr]

# [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

**Only exclude 'b' and ':' characters and return list**

[See @Coldspeed's solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49128699/9209546)

Comment: Trying to understand why you've brought numpy into this? The last two options are just repeats already mentioned. You can write the second option a bit better as well.

Comment: Finally, option 1 is likely not going to help OP because "Note that the fact that these characters are in the second position of each sublist is just an accident of my choice of example".

Comment: well done! I prefer `isinstance(x, (int, float))` if I know what my data is.

Comment: But I now see you had an identical solution, so I reference you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do list comprehension aswell but here is a variant with `del`.

```
lst = [[1,'b',2],[3,':',4],[5,':',6]]

for x in lst:
    for idx, y in enumerate(x):
        if y in {'b', ':'}:
            del x[idx]
            break
```

Of course this only works if there is only one special character. Otherwise you'd need to iterate over the sublists backwards.

Answer (score -1):

Just create more functions to make everything more readable:

```
INVALID_ENTRIES = {':', 'b'}

def is_relevant_entry(entry):
    return entry not in INVALID_ENTRIES

def clean_item(item):
    return list(filter(is_relevant_entry, item))

def clean_list(lst):
    return list(map(clean_item, lst))

a = [[1,'b',2],[3,':',4],[5,':',6]]
result = clean_list(a)
```

I think it is much better than these comprehension one-liners.

No loops, names convey the meaning and usage of the standard library :)

In python2 `map` and `filter` are eager so you don't need to wrap with `list`

Comment: Imho, *this is killing a mosquito with a sniper rifle*

Comment: I generally prefer to NOT use syntax. List comprehensions are very much syntax. They are a code smell for me (same goes for loops).

Comment: List comprehensions have their uses. About the only time they could be considered to smell is when they're used for side effects. Otherwise, they're an elegant and useful construct if used correctly.

Comment: They are very specific and become complex very fast. But sure - they have their uses. I never said they don't. Once the word "nested" crawls in, and then you add filtering... I'll opt out.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but you certainly have an interesting perspective! Sure, in terms of readability, I'd rather a loop than a list comprehension. But when you're using map or filter in the name of readability, that seems like a non-sequitur to me. Just my 2c!

Comment: `map` and `filter` are **extremely** readable, mainly because of their high usage in all contexts, but also because they have verb-names (comprehensions do not) which **convey what you are doing**. In all honesty - I can program in python (and I even use comprehensions occasionally) - but I **always** have to rewind in the middle of a nested comprehension. If I asked you: "What does `[x for x in y if x]` do?" you'd say "filter". Well, there is a standard-library function with that name.